# redirecting to /dev/null

Tags: shell-script, null

I'm reading an example bash shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script makes a backup of my home directory.

cd /home

# This creates the archive
tar cf /var/tmp/home_franky.tar franky > /dev/null 2>&1

# First remove the old bzip2 file.  Redirect errors because this generates some if the archive
# does not exist.  Then create a new compressed file.
rm /var/tmp/home_franky.tar.bz2 2> /dev/null
bzip2 /var/tmp/home_franky.tar

# Copy the file to another host - we have ssh keys for making this work without intervention.
scp /var/tmp/home_franky.tar.bz2 bordeaux:/opt/backup/franky > /dev/null 2>&1

# Create a timestamp in a logfile.
date >> /home/franky/log/home_backup.log
echo backup succeeded >> /home/franky/log/home_backup.log
```

I'm trying to understand the use of `/dev/null 2>&1` here. At first, I thought this script uses `/dev/null` in order to gracefully ignore errors, without causing the script to crash (kind of like try catch exception handling in programming languages). Because I don't see how using tar to compress a directory into a tar file could possibly cause any type of errors.

Comment: Just a trick to avoid unnecessary output. As for why tar can cause errors: because the target directory does not exist, because the source doesn't, because you don't have write access to the target, or read to the source, because `tar` is not in your $PATH, because `tar` crashed (you never know), because there's no space left on the device, because the `tar` version changed and now requires different syntax, because the disk caused an I/O error. I'm sure you could find more.

Answer (score 394, accepted):

No, this will not prevent the script from crashing. If any errors occur in the `tar` process (e.g.: permission denied, no such file or directory, ...) the script will still crash.

This is because of using `> /dev/null 2>&1` will redirect all your command output (both `stdout` and `stderr`) to `/dev/null`, meaning no outputs are printed to the terminal.

By default:

```
stdin  ==> fd 0
stdout ==> fd 1
stderr ==> fd 2
```

In the script, you use `> /dev/null` causing:

```
stdin  ==> fd 0
stdout ==> /dev/null
stderr ==> fd 2
```

And then `2>&1` causing:

```
stdin  ==> fd 0
stdout ==> /dev/null
stderr ==> stdout
```

Comment: As of understanding `> /dev/null 2>&1` , this command result in `stderr ==> stdout`, so stderr still get printed to stdout??

Comment: @WeishiZeng: Yes, but at that time, `stdout` was pointed to `/dev/null`.

Comment: why mention `&` before fd `1` (stdout) and not before fd `2` (stderr) ?

Comment: probably not too important, but what is `fd`?

Comment: @kev https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor

Comment: Why does: `CMD > /dev/null 2>&1` work but `CMD 2>&1 > /dev/null` still give me STDERR?

Comment: Recommended: Use `2>& 1` in code examples to stress that the number and the ampersand are considered to be part of the redirection operator.  It is common for redirection to a file to have a space between `>` and `/path/to/file`, redirection to a file descriptor is essentially the same thing.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld Check http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_05 `[n]>&word` is the general form. There's no need for space here.

Comment: fd mens File Descriptor. Linux treats all devices as files.

Comment: @dbmikus You should have asked that as a separate question :) Nevertheless, the first one says _"redirect writes to file descriptor 1 to `/dev/null`, and then redirect writes to file descriptor 2 to the same place as the writes to file descriptor 1 are going"_ . The second one says "redirect writes to file descriptor 2 to the same place as the writes to file descriptor 1 are going, and then redirect writes to file descriptor 1 to `/dev/null`". I also struggled with this. Idea from a coworker and from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/497215/12428 for a detailed description.

Comment: @törzsmókus In `CMD 2>&1 >/dev/null`, at the time `2>&1` occurs, file descriptor 1 still point to standard out, so standard error will go to standard out. `> /dev/null` takes no effect.

Comment: @cuonglm `> /dev/null` _does_ take effect; the stdout (fd 1) of `CMD` goes there (i.e. disappears), and the stderr (fd 2) of `CMD` goes to the standard out.

Comment: @törzsmókus I mean take no effect to previous standard error redirection.

Comment: *"... the script will still crash."* -- No it will not crash, because `set -o errexit` is not set. Only the `tar` command will fail and the rest of the script will happily continue on trying to execute nonsense commands on non-existing files.

Answer (score 102):

To understand "redirecting to `/dev/null`" easily, write it out explicitly. Below is an example command that tries to remove a non-existent file (to simulate an error).

```bsh
rm nonexisting.txt 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

1. is for stdout. Sends info logs to /dev/null
2. is for stderr. Sends error logs to /dev/null

Below are couple of enhancements.

Enhancement 1: You can replace `1>` with just `>`. This is because `1` is the default stdout and you can ignore mentioning defaults.

```bsh
rm nonexisting.txt > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

Enhancement 2: You can replace the 2nd file redirect (`> /dev/null`) with a file descriptor duplication (`>& 1`). This is because `/dev/null` is *already pointed to by stdout `1`*.

```bsh
rm nonexisting.txt 1> /dev/null 2>& 1
```

Enhancement 3: This is such a common operation, that many shells have a shortened form of this as a single `&>` operator.

```bsh
rm nonexisting.txt &> /dev/null
```

My suggestion: Stick to the first option. Write out the commands explicitly instead of using pointers. Takes little to no extra effort but much easier to understand and explain.

Comment: this is actually quite the better answer, as it is a "this means that", rather than a generic "this does that"

Comment: Superb, I've been struggling to understand this topic for ages, finally I know how to use it. Explicit commands are the best way to explain and to memorize.

Comment: "Stick to the first option" is good advice. "Enhancement 3" is substantially less portable.

Comment: @thomp45793 Portability? Readability? __no __my __attribute__((cringe)) __code __looks __attribute__((allways_inline)) __like __this

Comment: Glad I could give the 100th upvote. Finally I understand this. Admittedly I never put much effort into learning it, but after less than the one minute it took to read through your answer, I believe I can now after 20-some years finally stop Googling it once a month.

Answer (score 25):

> I'm trying to understand the use of "> /dev/null 2>&1" here.

(note that I added the redirection before `/dev/null` in your question.)

The above would redirect the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to `/dev/null`.  It works by merging the `STDERR` into the `STDOUT`.  (Essentially all the *output* from the command would be redirected to the [null device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null).)

> ... without causing the script to crash (kind of like try catch exception handling in programming languages).

It's not quite like a `try/catch` or anything.  It simply *silences* any sort of output (including error) from the command.

> Because I don't see how using tar to compress a directory into a tar
>   file could possibly cause any type of errors.

It could result in errors for a number of reasons, including:

- Inadequate permissions on the file(s) you're attempting to archive or on the file that you're attempting to write to
- Lack of disk space in order to create the archive

Answer (score 25):

When you run CMD > /dev/null 2>&1

STDOUT redirects to /dev/null, and then STDERR redirects to THE ADDRESS of STDOUT, which has been set to /dev/null , consequently both STDOUT and STDERR point to /dev/null

Oppositely, when you run CMD 2>&1 >/dev/null

STDERR redirects to THE ADDRESS of STDOUT (File descriptor 1 in that moment, or /proc/self/fd/1), and then STDOUT redirects to /dev/null , but STDERR keeps redirecting to fd1!! As a result the normal output from STDOUT is discarded, but the errors coming from STDERR are still being written onto the console.

Comment: A more brief way to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null` is: `command &> /dev/null`.

Comment: `&> /dev/null` did not work for me in a script file, outputting the whole stderr after the script is completed, but `> /dev/null 2>&1` worked well.

Comment: This explanation helped (me) more than the other (also helpful) answers.  Great description!

Answer (score 4):

```
cat nonexistantfile.txt &>/dev/null
```

This redirects both STDOUT both STDIN
And  is equivalent to

```
cat nonexistantfile.txt >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score -3):

### Bash I/O Redirection

[image: redirection definition]

---

This code:

```
command > filename 2>&1
```

- `> filename` redirects `stdout` to `filename`
- (`2>&1`) redirects `stderr` to `stdout` (now `filename`)

(file descriptor 1 is the default, so `>` is short for `1>`)

[Here is the ABSG explanation (Ch. 20)](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#IO-REDIRECTION).

Another common example:

```
command >>/dev/null 2>&1
```

redirects `stderr` and `stdout` to `/dev/null` ... which means to ***nowhere***. Things sent to `/dev/null` are not saved, cached, or remembered in any way.

They are just sent to '***nowhere***' and forgotten. This is a way of running programs and making sure they produce NO output and will never be seen on the command line or in a log file.

---

I see this type of question quite a bit ... mainly because I've had to look it up myself since I haven't been coding in years. Here is some handy information from the ABSG:

> "Redirection simply means capturing output from a file, command, program, or script and sending it as input to another file, command, program, or script."

```
2>&1 
# Redirects stderr to stdout.

command >>filename 2>&1
# Appends both stdout and stderr
#+  to the file "filename" ...
```

---

**ABSG: Advanced Bash Scripting Guide:** The [Chapter 20 link above](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#IO-REDIRECTION) is a link to the I/O redirection page of the open source [tldp.org](https://www.tldp.org/) document called the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html) by Mendel Cooper. It is listed as "An in-depth exploration of the art of shell scripting
" and I absolutely agree. It is a terrific resource and has tons of answers to all sorts of crazy situations.

**Other Valuable Resources:** There are many valuable resources in the current/maintained section *(in several handy formats like html, pdf, text, etc)* on the [Linux Documentation Project Guides](https://www.tldp.org/guides.html) page. Here are a few I have found useful:

- [Bash Guide for Beginners](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/) by Machtelt Garrels
- [Introduction to Linux](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/index.html) by Machtelt Garrels
- [GNU/Linux Command-Line Tools Summary](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/index.html) by Gareth Anderson
- [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/index.html) by Binh Nguyen
- [Securing & Optimizing Linux](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-The-Ultimate-Solution-v2.0.pdf) (pdf only): The Ultimate Solution by Gerhard Mourani

Comment: No, redirections are handled left to right. In your example, standard output is redirected to `filename`, then standard error is redirected to wherever standard output is currently going (to `filename`). If it was the opposite way around, standard error would end up on the terminal while only standard output was redirected to `filename`.  Also, in `command >file1 2>file2`, `file2` would not be created if `file1` could not be created (no matter whether `file1` and `file2` were actually totally different pathnames).

Comment: I've gotta say, including anything from google as a response hurts my soul because I already Googled it and then came here (╥_╥)