# Difference between >/dev/null 2>&1 & and </dev/null &>/dev/null &

Tags: terminal, launcher

I've been using the following to launch programs from terminals:

```
program_name >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

But recently I came across [this webpage](https://www.tecmint.com/run-linux-command-process-in-background-detach-process/) where the following method was recommended:

```
program_name </dev/null &>/dev/null &
```

Now, I know what the first one means. It means to point stderr to stdout and stdout to /dev/null i.e. both stderr and stdout is now pointed to null.

But what does the second one means? And which one is more suitable for launching programs headlessly from terminal?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are, by default, three "standard" files open when you run a program, standard input (`stdin`), standard output (`stdout`), and standard error (`stderr`).  In Unix, those are associated with "file descriptors" (`stdin` = 0, `stdout` = 1, `stderr` = 2).  By default, all three are associated with the device that controls your terminal (the interface through which you see content on screen and type input into the program).

The shell gives you the ability to "redirect" file descriptors.  The `>` operator redirects output; the `<` redirects input.

For example:

```
program_name > /dev/null
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
program_name 1> /dev/null
```

Redirects the output to file descriptor 1 ('stdout') to `/dev/null'

Similarlly,

```
program_name 2> /dev/null
```

Redirects the output to file descriptor 2 ('stderr') to '/dev/null'

You might want to redirect *both* `stdout` and `stderr` to a single file, so you might think you'd do:

```
program_name > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

But that doesn't handle interleaving writes to the file descriptors (the details behind this are a different question).  To address this, you can do:

```
program_name > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Which says "redirect writes to file descriptor 1 to `/dev/null` and redirect writes to file descriptor 2 to the same place as the writes to file descriptor 1 are going".  This handles interleaving writes to the file descriptors.

That option is so common that some shells include a short-hand that is shorter and functionally equivalent:

```
program_name &> /dev/null
```

Finally, you can redirect input in the same way that you redirect output:

```
program_name < /dev/null
```

Will redirect file descriptor 0 (`stdin`) from `/dev/null`, so if the program tries to read input, it'll get EOF.

Putting that all together:

```
program_name </dev/null &>/dev/null &
```

Say (1) run `program_name`, (2) redirect standard input from `/dev/null` (`</dev/null`), (3) redirect both file descriptors 1 and 2 (`stdout` and `stderr`) to `/dev/null` (`&>/dev/null`), and (4) run the program in the background (`&`).

Comment: Why does `&` in `&>/dev/null` means `fd 1` and `fd 2`? Is that the short-hand you talked about above this ending?

Comment: The last `&` is to run the program in the background -- it's unrelated to redirection.  `>` redirects standard output; `2>` redirects standard error.

Comment: is `program_name </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &` equivalent to `program_name </dev/null &>/dev/null &`?

Comment: Yes, like I said in my answer above, `foo &> bar` is a short-hand for `foo > bar 2&1`.  The `< /dev/null` means the same in both instances.

Answer (score -1):

For > /dev/null You are actually nullifying the thing.

While for 2>&1  You are redirecting any error stream text to the output stream. This will be best understand when someone tries to run a command that actually throws error when executed. Just use that command twice once as it is and another time with 2>&1 post your command.

Hope this will help at least novice users.
Thanks.